# Decrease height of card to fit any screen size without cutting off the overlay at the bottom

Tags: html, css, reactjs, ionic-framework

[image]

Trying to get my cards to adapt to different screen heights but the overlay with the text keeps getting cut off.

Is there a way to decrease the height of the card from the top of the image not the bottom so I don't cut off the text I have on the overlay?

```
<div className="HomeButtons-body">
                    <IonCard className="top-card"
                        routerLink="/tabs/home/discovery"
                        routerDirection="forward"
                    >
                        <IonImg className="image" src={djImage}></IonImg>
                        <div className="overlay1">
                            <p className="title">Discovery</p>
                            <p className="subtitle">Subtitle</p>
                        </div>
                        
                    </IonCard>
</div>
```

//css

```
    .HomeButtons-body{
        text-align: left;
    
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-top: 1vh;
    }
    
    
    .top-card{
        border-radius: 5%;
        height: 30vh;
        /* height: 230px; */
        background-color: black;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
        position: relative;
        
    }
    
    .overlay1 {
      position: absolute; 
      background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
      background: rgb(228, 22, 123, 0.75); /* Black see-through */
      color: #f1f1f1; 
      width: 100%;
      height: 9vh;
      opacity: 1 !important;
      color: white;
      font-size: 6vw;
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 20px;
      text-align: left;
      margin-top: -12vh;
    }
```

Comment: your `overlay` position depends on the viewport. Try to use `top` instead of the negative margin.